# 'Pre-mature EOF' and 'Bad Character' errors

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I have written Flex stuff in a previous class but none of my previously working code is solving the issue I am having.

I have searched around StackOverflow for a solution but none of them have solved it.

I have:

- Checked I have no errant spaces in the %{ ... %} area
- Tried using #include <'iostream>
- Tried %option noyywrap

Here is my code (I removed all the tokens and such because there is a lot of them):

```
%{

...

int numLines = 0;

void printTokenInfo(char* tokenType, char* lexeme);

void handleComments(char* text);

%}

WSPACE  [ \t\r]+
NEWLINE \n
DIGIT [0-9]
LETTER [a-zA-Z]
IDENT ({LETTER}|_)({LETTER}|{DIGIT}|_)* 
INTCONST {DIGIT}+
CHARCONST "'"{LETTER}+"'"

%%

... 

%%

// User-written code goes here
void printTokenInfo(char* tokenType, char* lexeme) 
{
    printf("A");
    printf("TOKEN: %s LEXEME: %s\n", tokenType, lexeme);
}

void handleComments(char* text) 
{
    printf("%s\n", text);
}

int yywrap() { return 1; }

int main() 
{
    do {
        yylex();
    } while (!feof(yyin));
    return 0;
}
```

Here is how I am compiling and running it:

```
flex FILENAME.l
g++ lex.yy.c -o lexer
lexer < INPUT.txt
```

And the instructor provided us with input files but none of them have worked. They all fail with 'premature EOF' or 'bad character'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think I finally discovered the answer... Try running it with the complete path rather than just the name of your compiled lexer. I discovered the 'actual' path by running it under gdb (Which admittedly should have been my first instinct).

```
gdb lexer
(gdb) run < INPUT.txt
```

Originally, I was trying to run it with:

```
lexer < INPUT.txt
```

But I discovered by running it with gdb that this worked:

```
/nethome/users/mjc7w6/Classes/lexer < INPUT.txt
```

Edit: Someone chimed in on my Facebook with a further improvement. If the above solution fixes it for you, you might need to edit your ~/.bashrc with the following:

```
export PATH=/nethome/users/mjc7w6/Classes:$PATH
```

Or however you find that path to be set-up.